# How to create a batch file which will prompt for the User's name and password and then writes them into registry?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Please be so kind and give me a hint for the following issue: I have to make two Windows registry string values, let say "USER" and "PASSWORD", but from a batch file (.bat), meaning the user double clicks the batch file, "TEST.BAT" and then a cmd window opens, it promts the text "Enter username", he types the username, after it promts "Enter Password" the user types his password and then the window closes.
After successfully ran, the bach file "TEST.BAT" will make two Windows registry string values named "USER" and "PASSWORD" and theirs values are exactly what the user had entered at promt window.
If I just want to make a batch file which will insert the two values I can use "reg add" using the following syntax:

#### reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\SSIS /v USER /t REG_SZ /d "JOHN" /f

#### reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\SSIS /v PASSWORD/t REG_SZ /d "123qwe." /f

But how can I make it one batch file which will promt the user for its username and password? (without C# console application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy.

```
@echo off
set /p username="Please enter your username: "
set /p passwd="Please enter your password: "
cls
reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\SSIS /v USER /t REG_SZ /d %username% /f
reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\SSIS /v PASSWORD/t REG_SZ /d %passwd% /f
exit
```

be aware, that as you type your password into the console it is visible. There is a way to hide the password, but it is very uncommon. Let me know, when you need it.

Comment: Thank you so much, easy indeed, if you know it, of course:) But if I need to hide the text typed? (not to show what the user types)?

Comment: See this post here: http://www.sysstem.at/2013/06/windows-command-line-password-function/
It is very slow and you can't have special characters in your pw. For this you need to use a exe file.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you know that this is not very secure since you are storing an unencrypted password in the registry.  With that in mind... this is not perfect, but better than typing for all to see and it is pure batch.  It opens another window that is quite difficult to read.  Adjust colors to your liking.  Unfortunately black on black is not an option.  Replace the "set /p passwd=" line and the "cls" from the syss solution with this:

```
SET TempFile=%TEMP%\%~n0.txt
IF EXIST %TempFile% DEL /q %TempFile%
ECHO.Enter Password in the Password window and press ENTER
START "Enter Password Below" /wait CMD /c "MODE con cols=40 lines=1 & COLOR AB & SET /p "In=Enter Password^> " & IF DEFINED In CALL ECHO.%%In%%>"%TempFile%""
IF EXIST "%TempFile%" FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%TempFile%") DO SET "password=%%A" & DEL /q %TempFile%
```

Comment: Thanks a million:) Worked like a charm. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 1):

try this and get an error message:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set /p "username=enter your username: "
set /p "passwd=enter your password: "
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\SSIS" /v USER /t REG_SZ /d "%username%" /f || echo FAIL && echo success
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\SSIS" /v PASSWORD/t REG_SZ /d "%passwd%"/f || echo FAIL && echo success
```